# iofgets.c no such file or directory

Tags: c, file-io, fgets

I need to work with many files to look for some info inside them (they are composed by 3 columns of numbers). As I also need to look for files in sub directories I am using the ftw function. As far of today, the structure of my directories were:

> ```
> -TOP
>   -Sub 1
>     -200 files
>   -Sub 2
>     -200 files
>   ...
>   -Sub 6
>     -200 files
> ```

In this case, my program runs very well. Today I tried with directories that all have 800 files instead of 200. When it looks for the first subdirectory, all goes fine but when the program reads the next one it fails. It gives me the error:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   _IO_fgets( buf=hex number, "the value of x the value of y the value of z \n", n=8196, fp=0x0) at iofgets.c:50 50    iofgets.c no such file or
>   directory.

were the values of x, y and z are the values of the last row of the file that it is reading. So, why if it recognizes the file which truely exists, is it giving me this error at the end of the file? Apart from this I cannot undestand the next few things:

1. If I read file 1, file 2 gets me the error but if instead of file 2 I read file 3 after file 1, it also gives me the same error.
2. If instead of starting from file 1, I start from file 2, file 2 is ok but the error is in file 3.
3. I don't read all 800 files. I read from a determinated value (start in code). If I change this value, I am getting the error in a previous or posterior file but around after it reads ~ 360 files or so.

   I am running this on lubuntu 13.10. Compiled with gcc 5.1.

   ```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <dirent.h>
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <ftw.h>

   int MAX_BUFFER = 8192;

   int lookfor(const char* file, const struct stat* ptr, int flags){
     char look[MAX_BUFFER];
     struct stat structure;
     stat(strdup(file), &structure);

     if (S_ISDIR(structure.st_mode)){
        strcpy(look, file);
        File *filee;
        char lookk[MAX_BUFFER], buffer[MAX_BUFFER];
        //[BLA BLA BLA BLA]

        struct dirent **namelist;
        int n = scandir(look, &namelist,0,versionsort);
        int i, ii;
        int start = 177;

        for (i=0; i<n; i++){
               //[BLA BLA BLA BLA]
           if (ii> start){
             sprintf(lookk, "%s/%s", look, namelist[i]->d_name);
             filee = fopen(lookk,"r");
             double x,y,z;
             while(fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER, filee) != NULL){
                sscanf(buffer, "%le%le%le", &x, &y, &z);
                //BLA BLA
             }
             start++;
           }
           //BLA BLA BLA
        }
     }
    return 0;
   }

   int main( int argc, char *argv[]){
      ftw(argv[1], lookfor, FTW_D); //arg1 is the name of top dir.
      return 1;
   }
   ```

Comment: In that error message, you see the `fp=0x0` part? It means you are calling `fgets` with a `NULL` file pointer. Always, ***always***, check for failure for functions that can fail (like `fopen`).

Comment: Ok, but in that case, why does it fail after 300 files? If what you say is correct, I should have the error on the first file read it, isn't it?

Comment: If `fopen` fail, you might want to print the error message (using e.g. [`perror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/perror) or [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) with [`errno`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno)) together with the file-name. That will tell you *what* went wrong, as well as which file you tried to open (and can verify that the name/path is correct). Before we (and more importantly you) know what's wrong there is no way for us to even guess at a solution to help you.

Comment: the code is using strdup(), but seems to never free the resulting malloc'd memory allocation

Comment: There's no `fclose(filee)`, so you're leaking files — and that is the sort of thing that leaves you failing after several hundred operations.

Comment: ftw() is a recursive function.  so it is probably running out of available stack space.

Comment: Inside bla bla bla there was a free(namelist); but I forgot fclose! Dammit. Thank you very much!